# How run make file in rpi4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, buildroot, crosstool-ng

I have built on ubuntu host the kernel/rootfs for rpi4 model b 64-bit with latest buildroot and using crosstoolng aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu and [raspberry pi os as source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git) . How can I run a make file in the rpi? I don't think buildroot has menuconfig option for opkg or apt-get to install make

Thanks

Comment: Anything not working when you run it as you would run it on other systems?

Comment: no, make doesn't work on rpi when building rpi os with buildroot, make utility is not installed. in my host it does work but that's ofc x-compiled

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find it in menuconfig, but in buildroot's built config dir i could edit raspberrypi4_64_defconfig:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_OPKG=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_OPKG_GPG_SIGN is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_OPKG_UTILS=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_OPKG_UTILS is not set
```